# How to create an array of 100 integers where every element of array is its index in c language

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I want to assign every array with its index and this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    int length = get_int("How many arrys do you need? ");
    int s[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        s[i] = i;
        printf("s[i] = %d\n", i);
    }
 }
```

when run

```
s[i] = 0
s[i] = 1
```

so I want replace `i` in the code with its index number like this:

```
s[0] = 0 
s[1] = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. That code already does what you want. Why do you want to replace `s[i]=i;` with some hard coded values? Without that you need to write 100 lines instead of a tiny loop.

Comment: Do you mean the assignment or the `printf`?

Comment: In POSIX, but not plain Standard C, you can use `$`: `printf("s[%1$d] = %1$d\n", i);`

Comment: *When run* Are you talking about your output? Please always be specific whether you mean executing an intruction or printing some output etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine regarding the initialization of the array.

The `printf` statement should be changed to print both the index and the value stored at the index:

```
    printf("s[%d] = %d\n", i, s[i]);
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int length = get_int("How many array elements do you need? ");
    if (length <= 0 || length > 1024) {
        printf("invalid length: %d\n", length);
        return 1;
    }
    int s[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        s[i] = i;
        printf("s[%d] = %d\n", i, s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your information I want ask you what is 1024 mean?

Comment: `if (length <= 0 || length > 1024)` is called a sanity test. If the user enters a negative number of one that is too large, defining a local array `int s[length];` will have undefined behavior (possibly a **stack overflow**). limiting the array length to `1024` seems both safe for current architectures and sufficient to illustrate the lesson. Much larger values may be possible on some systems, but anything larger than a few million will very likely cause problems.